# Can a I add more than 1 dimensions in an array at same axis?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am not getting the concept of dimensions/axis properly. I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
x = np.expand_dims(l,0)
print(x)
print(x.shape)
x = np.expand_dims(l,0)
print(x)
print(x.shape)
```

As the result I am getting:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
(1, 6)
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
(1, 6)
```

why am I not getting:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
(1, 6)
[[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]]
(1, 1, 6)
```

Comment: `expand_dims` makes a new array.  It does not modify the original (which your case is actually a `list`).  `x  = np.reshape(l, (1,1,6))` adds both dimensions at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `l` to `x` in your second attempt to extend the dimensions:

```
x = np.expand_dims(l,0)
x = np.expand_dims(x,0)
print(x.shape)
```

```
(1, 1, 6)
```